# How do I write a powershell script that gets the file with the most recent last write time from a folder?

Tags: powershell

The subject line says it all. I'd also like to do this using pipes.

I figured that I could use Get-ChildItem, Measure-Object and Where-Object, but Measure-Object doesn't like dates.

Should I have a script block which loops through each item returned from Get-ChildItem and does a comparison to see if it's the most recent? I thought that there should be a handy PS cmdlet for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
```